# WPF Project Generated from CMake has wrong VS context menus

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, cmake

[This project](https://github.com/bemehiser/cmake_csharp_example/) is a good example of what I'm trying to do, namely to generate a WPF C# project using CMake.

Everything works as expected, except the Project(Example)->Add context menu from Solution Explorer shows options for Windows Forms, and not for WPF.

[image: Should have WPF options, not WinForms]

Instead of these Window Forms options, I expect to see the following options (from a non-CMake project):

[image: The above should look like this]

What is missing from the CMake project to enable this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some careful comparison of the project files, the missing piece was ProjectTypeGuids in the generated .csproj file.

A WPF project should be set up in CMake with the following:

```
set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    # These GUIDs define the project types, which control things like what context menus are available in VS.
    # The first is WPF, the second is C#.
    VS_GLOBAL_PROJECT_TYPES "{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}"
)
```

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can mark it so that it can help more people

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
VS_GLOBAL_UseWPF "true"
```

I have a repo here with an example: https://github.com/joeloftusdev/dotnet_cmake_examples